# Null reference exception error on VS2010

Tags: windows-phone-7

I got a null reference exception problem on

```
var stream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/Vid_VGA_Client_.raw", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)).Stream;
```

I move my file to a new solution folder named Video. Then when I debug it I got an error with null reference exception.

Comment: Where do you get the null reference exception? The GetResourceStream returns null? If that's the case it couldn't find the file in the root folder of your app.

Comment: Make sure your file is set to an embedded reosource in the solution

Comment: the file i put inside a solution folder cant set it type..

Answer (score 0):

The call to `Application.GetResourceStream` isn't returning anything so the `.Stream` property access on the end is trying call a property on a null reference.

Of course, this is just a guess.

You need to fix the resource access path to include the new folder I believe, something like:

```
/Video/Vid_VGA_Client_.raw
```

Comment: i fix the resource acess path d but still come out null reference exception.
the troubleshooting tips is "use the new keyword to create an object instance. Check the determine if the object is null before calling the method